# TinyMCE 4 node duplication issue when updating selected node using setNode()

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

Using TinyMCE 4, I am trying to implement a button with a fairly straightforward functionality: For the selected (highlighted) node, I want to update its class by clicking that button.

I am updating the node by using the `setNode()` function. The problem is that, instead of just updating the existing node as expected, I am also getting a duplicate node.

For example, say I have this text in the tinyMCE body:

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Expected result after highlighting the text and clicking "MyButton":

```
<p class="updated">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

What I am getting instead:

```
<p class="updated">
    <p class="updated">This is a paragraph.</p>
</p>
```

So for some reason the node is being duplicated (or wrapped by the same node?) and I cannot understand why.

Relevant code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

tinymce.init({

    //...

    setup: function(editor){

        editor.addButton('MyButton', {
            name: 'MyButton',
            text: 'MyButton',
            icon: false,

            onclick: function() {
                var selectedNode = window.parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode(), //get the selected node
                    updatedNode  = $(selectedNode).addClass('updated'); //perform desired modifications to it
                    updatedNode  = updatedNode.get(0); //return the javascript element

                //update the node:
                window.parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setNode(updatedNode);

            }//end onclick
        });//end addButton

    }//end setup

});//end tinymce.init

</script>
```

---

**EDIT:** I finally found a workaround for this. Instead of creating a new node (`updatedContent`) and then using it to set the selected node content (`window.parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent(updatedContent);`), one should directly update the selected node (`selectedNode`). Like so:

```
$(selectedNode).addClass('updated');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood what is happening.

Take a look at this bit of code:

```
var updatedNode = $(selectedNode).addClass('updated');
```

This line does actually two things: It adds a class to the selected node BUT it also stores this result in the updatedNode.

So up to now, the DOM should look like this:

```
<p class="updated">This is some paragraph.</p>
```

Then this line runs:

```
window.parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setNode(updatedNode);
```

which actually does exactly what it promises: it sets the content of the selected node...

So it takes the selected node, which at this point looks like this:

```
<p class="updated">This is some paragraph.</p>
```

and sets its content: In other words, it replaces its **content** - so whatever is between the `<p class="updated">` and `</p>` tags - with the `updatedNode`, which looks like this:

```
<p class="updated">This is some paragraph.</p>
```

So it very rightly replaces `This is some paragraph` with `<p class="updated">This is some paragraph.</p>`. And thus we get the unexpected result...

`<p class="updated"><p class="updated">This is some paragraph.</p></p>`

---

I see now that the problem is very subtle, and specific to my case really. However, I decided to post the explanation anyway, in the hope it might help someone one day.